Is it possible to compress or parition existing huge table in place for mariadb?
I have a mariadb database set up for logging experiment data. In one of the tables, I store huge raw images every row. With a few million rows each containing 3 512*512px images, I run out of disk space. I have 12TB disk and the database has consumed ~10TB. The difference between images is small, so I believe there is a lot of room for compression. I want to consider compression the database, but with limited free space I want a method to compress it in place.
I use mariadb 10.3.39 on Ubuntu 20.04. I am not an expert on database, but I am happy to learn more.
I tried:
ALTER TABLE images ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8 ALGORITHM=INPLACE;

and I got:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALGORITHM=INPLACE' at line 1 

I also considered maybe I can partition my table into chunks, and comrpress each partition individually. However I am also not sure if partitioning existing table requires more space. I would like to get some recommendation before trying blindly.

FWIW, this is one of the reasons you shouldn't store files in the database. They're meant to be stored in a file system on disk.

Short answer:  No
Long answer:

What type of images are they?  Most formats (.jpg, etc) are already compressed, so compression has no benefit.
InnoDB's COMPRESSED gives only about 2:1 compression, even in the best of situations (numbers and strings, not images).  OTOH, the compression is automatic so there is no need to compress some parts and not other.
What is the largest table?  How big is it?  Many types of change to a table require copying the table over.  That is, during the operation, you need room for a copy of the table.  Specifically, INPLACE won't work.
MariaDB does not have a way to compute the difference between two images.  That is what you need.  Even if you find such, there is a lot of programming to implement it.
To initially PARTITION your 10GB would take a spare 10GB (which you don't have).
Very few operations can be performed on a single PARTITION; this eliminates your hypothetical benefit of partitioning.

Here's a thought...

Experiment with sample BLOBs (512MB each?).  Do this in your app, not MariaDB.
If you get a significant shrinkage, then proceed.
Walk through the table via its PRIMARY KEY.  Read the blob(s), compress them, and store them back into the table.  This will take a long time and apparently save no disk space.  (More on that later.)
Meanwhile, change the app code one of two ways:  (1) keep track of how far along the compression -- so that it knows whether to uncompress when reading.  (2) Or look at the first few bytes to see if the blob is compressed (and uncompress if necessary).
When finished, the table will still be 10GB, but it will have lots of holes in it.  These should mostly be reused by future INSERTs.  Caveat:  The BLOB column is probably stored "off-record"; I do not know if freed-up blocks can be reused.  So I recommend performing some tests.
Eventually, the holes will be used up, and the new rows will lead to the table growing.

Or...
If you can live with "old" rows being deleted, see this for how to do such with minimal impact:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

The "images" are 5125122Byte BLOBs . The context is I am logging experimental data in a physics experiment, so we have raw data. Across consecutive images are very similar so there is not that much "information" but we have to keep raw data as an archive. Old data is not accessed very often. All processing happens elsewhere. That's why I think compression will greatly reduce size, and partitioning makes a lot of sense to organize old vs new data. This single table is the dominating one and is 9TB, other tables are much smaller.

@hzlin, I added information on why partitioning is impossible and two ways to solve your dilemma.

Thanks for the suggestion. This seems to be one of the most flexible way, but requires changes in application side to support it, so I have to think whether it is worth the work, or just brute force with more hard drive.

Basically a good compressed image even, if it is flawless will better than a compressed Row.
but as MARIAFB doesn't support compression in a ALTER TABLE
What you can do is
CREATE tABLE tmp1(Images blob)

INSERT INTO tmp1 VALUES(RPAD('', 65535, CHAR(7)));

CREATE TABLE cmp2 (i Blob COMPRESSED=zlib)
SELECT images FROM tmp1


Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


fiddle

Sorry I did not understand it fully. It seems that you are suggesting compression in my application side, instead of on the database side? I can keep it in mind, but we have other processing pipeline build around it, so we prefer to compress on the database side if possible.

Or, are you referring to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/storage-engine-independent-column-compression/ the compression attribute for each column?

yes, when you compress the data lets says flawless png and save it in a blob you will have the same as a bitmapn with in my example zlib compression, column conpression will not be better than te row compression
